# How to stop fluid inflow?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have fluid simulation with an inflow object. I want the inflow to go for 2 seconds, then have the inflow stop (so no more fluid is added) but keep the simulation going  (so the existing fluid sloshes around).

However, I do not see any way to set start and ending values on my inflow object.

How do I stop inflow at a certain frame/time in my simulation?

Comment: In my experience, when I keyframe the inflow to be checked off, one the animation reaches that point, the domain box comes back into view, obstructing the entire simulation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Animate the Fluid's *Enabled* property:

   [image: Fluid panel in Blender]
2. By right-clicking on it and *Inserting Keyframes*:

   [image: Right click menu on Enabled checkbox]

Comment: This is very cryptic. Where is this "enable" property

Comment: @leigero When you add an inflow object it is very obvious where it is. I added a picture for you :)

Comment: In Blender 2.9 this control has been renamed "Use Flow"

Answer (score -1):

scale down the inflow obj , or animate its position to make it get out of the domain when you need it stopped and bake ;)

Comment: Please expand your answer so it can be useful for other people who come across it. As it stands, it does't seem to have enough detail to be useful.

Comment: As someonewithpc said, please give further information, maybe even an example or provide some images. There will be more people having this question and not only one. Also consider taking a look at [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The correct answer has already been given, and this new "answer" is not good (while it may work, it comes with different problems that you don't get with the correct answer above). I can't see why it should be expanded. If anything, it should be deleted.

Comment: @Jbergman There is no reason an alternative, correct solution should be deleted.