# Blender Fluid Simmulation: How to turn on and off the fluid appearing from inflow?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I am working on a tea set animation where the teapot pours tea in a teacup.
Now the issue is the fluid starts emitting from the inflow right from the first frame. I checked for an earlier post regarding the same question in the link below

[How to stop fluid inflow?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43797/how-to-stop-fluid-inflow)

Now I am using Blender 2.8 and the enabled option isn't there in the 'inflow' type option

plus you cannot animate the 'flow' option as well. I did try animating the velocities but at 0m/s the fluid keeps dripping rather than a complete stop.

In short, how do you close and open a tap?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.8 they changed the name. Instead of being called "Enabled" it's just called "Flow".

Keyframe that toggle on and off and it will give you exactly what you want.